# Eclipse Tomcat Server Configuration resets everytime I reboot the Server on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

My question is how do you save a configuration setting so that it permanently saves. Right now, I'm creating a dynamic webpage that allows users to upload photos. I user  as the directory to save the photos. It works if I save the Server.conf file, and then boot the server. If I reboot the server a bit later on, it resets that file. How do I permanently save it? I'm working on Tomcat 7 through eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main things which need to be considered while running a web app server.

Where the code (tomcat bin ) located and web apps are located.From the best practices point of view,eclipse saves webapp in a separate folder which is different from where tomcat exists.

By default this is a temp folder created by eclipse .This details can be seen in tomcat configuration of eclipse.

If you point the webapp folder to some concerete folder say /users/abc/xyz location rather than tmp  will resolve this issue.